# How to show that $\lim_{p\to 0}\frac{pe^{2tp}}{1-e^{2tp}(1-p)}=(1+2t)^{-k}$

Tags: calculus, limits

How would I find the following limit? I am thinking I might need to do a Taylor expansion of the exponentials but it hasn't worked out nicely. Thanks for the help.

$$\lim_{p\to 0} \left( \frac{pe^{2tp}}{1-e^{2tp}(1-p)} \right)^k$$

The answer is $(1+2t)^{-k}$.

Comment: Naive application of L'Hopital's:
$$\begin{eqnarray}
\lim\limits_{p\to 0}\left(\frac{pe^{2tp}}{1-e^{2tp}(1-p)}\right)^k &=&\left(\lim\limits_{p\to 0}\frac{pe^{2tp}}{1-e^{2tp}(1-p)}\right)^k\\ &=&\left(\lim\limits_{p\to 0}\frac{e^{2tp}+2p^2e^{2tp}}{2pe^{2tp}(1-p)-e^{2tp}}\right)^k\\ &=&\left(\lim\limits_{p\to 0}\frac{e^{2tp}+2p^2e^{2tp}}{2pe^{2tp}-(e^{2tp}+2p^2e^{2tp})}\right)^k\\
\end{eqnarray}$$
Perhaps examine similarity to $\frac{x}{x-y}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried l'Hospital's rule?
$$
\lim_{p \to 0} \frac{pe^{2tp}}{1-e^{2tp}(1-p)} = \lim_{p \to 0} \frac{e^{2tp}+p(2t)e^{2tp}}{e^{2tp} - (1-p)(2t)e^{2tp}} = \lim_{p \to 0} \frac{1+2tp}{1-(1-p)(2t)} = \frac {1}{1-2t}
$$
Just use the product rule and the case $k=1$ then.

Hope that helps,